# ReSharper calls inspection does not find a method

Tags: resharper, inspection

With R# 2017.3 I'm trying to find out whether method A through a call chain eventually might call method B.

So, I'm using Inspect->Incoming calls and try to use the filter field providing the method B name. Even though I know for sure that the method B is in the call tree, the Inspection UI does not find it.

However, if I click many times on "Expand All" and the method B appears in the UI, finally the search to find it.

Is this a bug or there is some setting that controls this behavior (e.g. nesting level)?

Comment: That question looks more appropriate for a post on [resharper community](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366389-ReSharper-Community)

Comment: This is similar to the halting problem. ReSharper simply cannot traverse back all incoming calls recursively. It could search for indefinite depth. The search filter only applies to what is loaded in the tree view.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer from JetBrains:

> This behavior is by design because the calculation of the enеire call hierarchy at once could take a very long time.